# Error al hacer una busqueda en PHP

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql

Estoy haciendo un CRUD en PHP el cual tiene interesados y cursos. Quiero hacer que se pueda buscar interesados por nombre o apellido o ambos. Cuando busco ambos me anda perfectamente, cuando quiero buscar por uno o por otro me tira el siguiente error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'S', "SQLSTATE[H"... is not valid JSON
```

La peticion a la base de datos es la siguiente:

```
public static function buscarInteresado($data)
{
    try {
        if ($data['nombre'] != '' and $data['apellido'] != ''){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM public.interesado WHERE nombre = :nombre AND apellido = :apellido";
        } elseif ($data['nombre'] != '' and $data['apellido'] == '') {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM public.interesado WHERE nombre = :nombre";
        } elseif ($data['nombre'] == '' and $data['apellido'] != '') {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM public.interesado WHERE apellido = :apellido";
        }
        $stmt = Connection::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $data['nombre']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':apellido', $data['apellido']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    } catch (PDOException $th) {
        echo $th->getMessage();
    }
}
```

El controller es el siguiente:

```
<?php
require_once "../models/interesado.model.php";
$arrayName = array(
    'nombre' => $_POST['nombre'],
    'apellido' => $_POST['apellido'],
);
echo json_encode(Interesado::buscarInteresado($arrayName));
```

Y el codigo en JS es el siguiente:

```
this.buscar = () => {
    if (document.getElementById("nombre_search").value != "" || document.getElementById("apellido_search").value != "") {
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append("nombre", document.getElementById("nombre_search").value);
        form.append("apellido", document.getElementById("apellido_search").value);
        fetch("../controllers/buscar_interesado.php", {
            method: "POST",
            body: form,
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.tbody.innerHTML = "";
                data.forEach((item) => {
                    this.tbody.innerHTML += `
                        html
                    `;
            })})
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    } else {
        this.listado();
    }
}
```

Comment: Haz la consulta manualmente, tiene pinta de devolver un error SQLSTATE

Comment: ¿y has probado poniendo los bindParam dentro de esos condicionales en lugar de usarlos todos al final?  Lo digo porque quizás eso está provocando el error, pues si solo necesitas uno (en el caso de nombre o apellido solos) y defines dos quizás da ese error de SQLSTATE (ni idea, no lo puedo probar ahora)

Comment: poniendo los bindParam en los condicionales me tira `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br />
<b>"... is not valid JSON`

Comment: y me deja de funcionar con los 2 campos

Comment: No tiene ningún sentido lo que dices que te ocurre con tan solo el código de la pregunta. Algo más debe haber por alguna parte (quizás luego hay más código y peta después?). Es decir, antes te devolvia un error SQLSTATE, y ahora código HTML (que por cierto no aparece en la exposición de la pregunta).  Cuando he dicho lo de los bindParam me referia a duplicarlos, es decir, en el primer if pones los dos bindParam, en el sefgundo solo el del nombre y en tercero el del apellido (ejem, y mueve el `$stmt = Connection::getConnection()->prepare($sql);` antes de los **if** para que sepan que es $stmt

Comment: me sigue tirando el mismo error. Asi me quedo https://imgur.com/a/5YfGxCJ

Comment: Sí, asi decia yo. ¿Tambien con los dos campos a a vez?  No deberia en ese caso al menos, pues decias que te funcionaba y tal como lo tienes ahora vendria a ser lo mismo en ese caso.

Comment: jolin, perdon, ahora el que esta mal es el $sql, claro... mmm... vale, bueno, para salir del paso haz una cosa... quita el `$stmt = Connection::getConnection()->prepare($sql);` de arriba y lo pones en cada **if** entre medio de la variable $sql y el primer bindParam... al menos eso soluciona el caso de los dos campos a la vez, y quizas los otros (no creo que sea lo optimo pero de momento prueba a ver)

Comment: ahora si anda!!

Comment: me alegro :-)  Como decia, no es lo más optimo pero era para conseguir esquivar los errores.  La respuesta de @ffflabs es a lo que debes llegar a partir de aquí, refactorizando y optimizando el código, que ahora sí funciona. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que el formulario de frontend, que tú controlas, siempre envía los campos `nombre` y `apellido`. De todos modos, es más precavido usar [nullish coalesce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php),  para manejar la posibilidad de que un campo no venga y así evitar el famoso error `undefined array key`.

```
$arrayName = [
    'nombre' => $_POST['nombre'] ?? '',
    'apellido' => $_POST['apellido'] ?? '',
];
```

Tampoco haría daño asegurarse de trabajar con strings y no otro tipo de datos :

```
$arrayName = [
    'nombre' => strval($_POST['nombre'] ?? ''),
    'apellido' => strval($_POST['apellido'] ?? ''),
];
```

Lo importante es tener la seguridad de que al entrar en `buscarInteresado` el array `$data` sí tendrá dos propiedades, nombre y apellido, de tipo string. Sin importar que puedan estar en blanco.

---

- Si viene el nombre y el apellido se debe consultar los registros que coincidan para ambos.
- Si uno de ellos viene en blanco, se debe consultar sólo por el otro.
- Si vienen ambos en blanco correspondería devolver un arreglo vacío (porque así la salida es homogénea y sólo cambia la cantidad de resultados).

La solución propuesta funciona, pero no parece eficiente arreglar un problema con repetición de código. Podrías estructurarlo en cambio como:

```
public static function buscarInteresado($data)
{   
    if(empty($data['nombre']) && empty($data['apellido'])) {
      return [];
    }

    // cualquier bifurcación empieza así:
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM public.interesado WHERE 1=1  ";
    $params = [];

    if ($data['nombre'] !== '') {
        $sql .= ' AND nombre = :nombre ';
        $params[':nombre']=$data['nombre'];
    }

    if ($data['apellido'] !== '') {
        $sql .= ' AND apellido = :apellido ';
        $params[':apellido']=$data['apellido'];
    }

    try {
        $stmt = Connection::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        return  $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (PDOException $th) {
        return ['error'=> $th->getMessage()];  
    }
}
```

¿Qué es lo importante de esa solución?

**Primero** tu código original no tiene cómo manejar el escenario de ambos datos vacíos. Se gatillaría un error fatal por que `$stmt` no existe. El  try/catch no te cubre en este caso. En esta solución sí manejo ese caso de borde.

**Segundo**: el método debiera responder con el mismo tipo de dato o bien tirar una excepción. Tu código puede devolver un array, no devolver nada o tirar un error fatal. Yo devuelvo un array vacío, un array de resultados o incluso el mensaje de error en un array. El método no tiene por qué ser responsable de imprimir nada. Eso lo hace quien lo invoca.

**Tercero**:  En vez de usar `else if` ten en cuenta que el contenido o falta de él en un campo no depende del otro. Son dos `if` que pueden cumplirse a la vez o por separado.

**Cuarto** Partiendo de una sentencia SQL base, por cada parámetro no vacío se añade una condición a ella. La base termina con `WHERE  1=1`  porque es inofensivo y a cambio puedo empezar toda adición con `AND`  sin tener que revisar en qué `if` estoy metido.

**Quinto**: `PDOStatement::execute` acepta como argumento un array asociativo donde las llaves sean los placeholders declarados en tu query:

```
       $stmt->execute([
          ':nombre' => 'lucas',
          ':apellido' => 'leone'
       ]);
       return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

El contenido de ese array lo voy añadiendo dentro de mis `if` así que sólo contiene los campos no vacíos. Dato adicional: puedes omitir los dos puntos y usar el nombre de la llave tal como tiene en `$data`.

Esta implementación puede optimizarse un poco más, reutilizando para cada campo de la consulta una misma asignación condicional:

```
   $stmt = Connection::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM public.interesado WHERE 1=1  ";
   $params = [];
   
   foreach(['nombre','apellido'] as $campo) {
      if(!empty($data[$campo])) {
          $sql .= sprintf(' AND %s = :%s ',$campo, $campo);
          $params[$campo] = $data[$campo];
      }
   }
   $stmt->execute($params);
   $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Y con eso, el día de mañana puedes incorporar otro criterio de búsqueda con mínima modificación. Solamente lo añades al `foreach`

```
     foreach(['nombre','apellido','nacionalidad','estado_civil'] as $campo) {


     }
```

(posiblemente en ese escenario sea mejor validar el contenido de `$data` en el método en vez del ámbito global.)
}}

---

**Edit**: tenía un `AND` de más en la sentencia SQL

Comment: Hola! Todo muy perfecto explicado pero me tira el error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br />
<b>"... is not valid JSON`, por lo que al $stmt lo puse abajo del $sql y me tira el error `error
: 
"SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  error de sintaxis al final de la entrada\nLINE 1: SELECT * FROM public.interesado WHERE 1=1 AND \n `

Comment: quedando asi el codigo https://imgur.com/a/ktc8g6B

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCION**

Tenia que poner el $stmt en cada if quedando el codigo asi:

```
public static function buscarInteresado($data)
{
    try {
        if ($data['nombre'] != '' and $data['apellido'] != ''){

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM public.interesado WHERE nombre = :nombre AND apellido = :apellido";
            $stmt = Connection::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $data['nombre']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':apellido', $data['apellido']);

        } else if ($data['nombre'] != '' and $data['apellido'] == '') {

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM public.interesado WHERE nombre = :nombre";
            $stmt = Connection::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $data['nombre']);

        } else if ($data['nombre'] == '' and $data['apellido'] != '') {
            
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM public.interesado WHERE apellido = :apellido";
            $stmt = Connection::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':apellido', $data['apellido']);
            
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    } catch (PDOException $th) {
        echo $th->getMessage();
    }
}
```