# SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: Error de sintaxis al final de la entrada

Tags: php, postgresql

Estoy queriendo hacer una peticion a una db postgres con php pero me tira el siguiente error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  error de sintaxis al final de la entrada\nLINE 1: SELECT * FROM public.interesado WHERE 1=1 AND \n
```

El codigo de interesado.model.php es el siguiente:

```
public static function buscarInteresado($data)
    {   
        try {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM public.interesado WHERE 1=1 AND ";
            $stmt = Connection::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
            $params = [];
            
            foreach(['nombre','apellido'] as $campo) {
               if(!empty($data[$campo])) {
                   $sql .= sprintf(' AND %s = :%s ',$campo, $campo);
                   $params[$campo] = $data[$campo];
               }
            }
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $th) {
            return ['error'=> $th->getMessage()];  
        }
    }
```

La funcion es para buscar un interesado por nombre o apellido, o ambos.

Comment: Estás repitiendo el `AND`, prueba a declarar la variable así inicialmente: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM public.interesado WHERE 1=1 ";` Si no funciona, dinos lo que hay en `$data`, pues lo que haces en el `foreach` es un tanto extraño.

Comment: mueve esta línea: `$stmt = Connection::getConnection()->prepare($sql);` después del foreach, justo antes del execute, a ver si así funciona.  Y borra el **AND** de esta línea: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM public.interesado WHERE 1=1 AND ";`, pues en todo caso ya lo estás agregando dentro de cada ciclo del foreach otra vez.

Comment: y luego piensa que estas haciendo con el `$params`, pues no parece que lo uses para nada

Comment: Es que mirándolo friamente, en cada linea parece que tengas algun error de algun tipo... ¿de donde has sacado todo eso?

Comment: @masterguru https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/561118/error-al-hacer-una-busqueda-en-php/561153#561153 de ahi

Comment: como puedo hacer que ande?

Comment: lo has copiado mal o interpretado de forma libre y errónea... fíjajte en el **execute**... allí es donde debes usar el $params, y repasa el foreach porque no se entiende demasiado lo que haces alli, la verdad (al menos yo no lo habia visto así nunca)

Comment: `como puedo hacer que ande?` preguntas... pues siendo más cuidadoso con lo que copias y **entendiendo** exactamente lo que estas haciendo.  Te podría dar una solución, pero si no la vas a entender no me compensa, necesito que te sirva para algo, no tan solo copiarla y ale, lo siento.

Comment: ya lo pude solucionar, saque el $sql, $params y el foreach afuera del try, y luego pase en el execute $params

Comment: y en esa respuesta hay un error con el **AND**, eso sí que no es tuyo

Comment: ok, pues si quieres contribuir con la comunidad ponlo como respuesta, y así, si alguien detecta algun fallo o efecto colateral que no has visto te lo diran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debia acomodar un poco el codigo.

- Eliminar el "AND" en la variable $sql
- Pasar el parametro $params en el execute
- Sacar parte del codigo del try

Quedando el codigo asi:

```
public static function buscarInteresado($data)
{   
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM public.interesado WHERE 1=1";
    $params = [];
    
    foreach(['nombre','apellido'] as $campo) {
        if(!empty($data[$campo])) {
            $sql .= sprintf(' AND %s = :%s ',$campo, $campo);
            $params[$campo] = $data[$campo];
        }
    }
    try {
        $stmt = Connection::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    } catch (PDOException $th) {
        return ['error'=> $th->getMessage()];  
    }
}
```

Comment: vale, ya he entendido el foreach, y si, tiene buena pinta ahora. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Si la idea es buscar por nombre y/o apellido sí o sí, no te sirve iniciar tu consulta de este modo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM public.interesado WHERE 1=1 AND ";
```

Porque si no hay parámetros estarás enviando una consulta vacía al manejador. Es mejor controlar la situación de los datos.

Aquí lo haremos mediante un array llamado `$where`, lo llenaremos cuando haya datos y luego lo verificaremos y sólo entonces preparamos y ejecutamos la consulta:

```
$where=array();
$params=array();
foreach ($data as $k=>$v) {
    if(!empty($v)) {
        $where[] = sprintf('%s = :%s ',$k, $k);
        $params[":$k"] = $v;
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM public.interesado";
if ($where) {
    $sql .= " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $where);
    $stmt = Connection::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} else {
    //No hay criterios, haz lo que debas hacer
}
```